# Timers.Timer vs Threading.Timer on a Console application

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I've noticed that Timers.Timer and Threading.Timer behave differently on a Console application. Looks like in the Callback of ThreadingTimer, if I throw an exception, it will crash the app. However, if I throw an exception in the TimersTimer elapsed handler, it will not crash it.

Both methods are being executed on worker threads from the thread pool. I'd speculate that the ThreadingTimer somehow propagates the exception to the main thread and the TimersTimer is not.

I can't find an explanation for this behavior in MSDN, could you help me with this?

Below is an example of the behavior:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var healthMonitor = new HealthMonitor();
        healthMonitor.Start();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

internal class HealthMonitor
{
    private Timer _timersTimer;
    private System.Threading.Timer _threadingTimer;

    public void Start()
    {
        StartTimersTimer(); 
        // StartThreadingTimer();
    }

    private void StartThreadingTimer()
    {
        _threadingTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(
            ThreadingTimerCallback,
            null,
            TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5000),
            TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5000));
    }

    private void ThreadingTimerCallback(object state)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Throwing from ThreadingTimer..");
        throw new Exception("Exception from ThreadingTimer");
    }

    private void StartTimersTimer()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting timers...");
        _timersTimer = new Timer(5000);
        _timersTimer.Elapsed += TimersTimer_Elapsed;
        _timersTimer.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void TimersTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Throwing from TimersTimer...");
        throw new Exception("Exception from TimersTimer");
    }
}
```

Comment: System.Timers.Timer was meant as an easier-to-use timer class, back in .NET 1.0.  Unfortunately, back then easier-to-use meant a lot more than it does nowadays.  Way too much, *any* exception raised in the Elapsed event handler is swallowed without any diagnostic.  This requires you to write try/catch yourself or avoid the class.

Comment: You can easily see in the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/timers/system/timers/Timer.cs#dc67c9466604a3d9#references) that System.Timers.Timer just wraps a System.Threading.Timer. It just catches all exceptions thrown when raising the Elapsed event.

Comment: You don't have to look at the reference source—this fact is [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.elapsed.ASPX).

Comment: Thanks HansPassant, mike z, Cody Gray. That answer my question, would you guys write it as an answer or should I delete/remove my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As HansPassant, mike z and Cody Gray said, the answer is in MSDN, specifically:

> The Timer component catches and suppresses all exceptions thrown by
>   event handlers for the Elapsed event. This behavior is subject to
>   change in future releases of the .NET Framework.

Interestingly, the behavior is present since .Net 1.1, so looks like a change is not imminent.

Comment: And this is why I strongly recommend *not* using `System.Timers.Timer`. It's a bug hider.